# How Structure Map Automocker Inject works?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, structuremap, rhino-mocks, automocking

I have constructor containing IEnumerable parameter. When I try to Inject concrete object to automocker it is not used.

When I use wrapper class containing IEnumerable property all works as expected.

How can I test TestClass1?

### IEnumerable parameter

```
public class TestClass1
{
    public TestClass1(IEnumerable<IItem> items)
    {
        Items = items;
    }

    public IEnumerable<IItem> Items { get; private set; }
}

[TestMethod]
public void TestClass1Constructor()
{
    RhinoAutoMocker<TestClass1> autoMocker = new RhinoAutoMocker<TestClass1>();

    IEnumerable<IItem> items = new[] { MockRepository.GenerateMock<IItem>() };
    autoMocker.Inject(items);

    Assert.AreEqual(1, autoMocker.ClassUnderTest.Items.Count());
}
```

Result of the test is:

> Assert.AreEqual failed. Expected:<1>. Actual:<0>.

### Wrapper class parameter

```
public class TestClass2
{
    public TestClass2(WrapperClass numbersWrapper)
    {
        Items = numbersWrapper.Items;
    }

    public IEnumerable<IItem> Items { get; private set; }
}

[TestMethod]
public void TestClass2Constructor()
{
    RhinoAutoMocker<TestClass2> autoMocker = new RhinoAutoMocker<TestClass2>();

    WrapperClass numbers = new WrapperClass(new[] { MockRepository.GenerateMock<IItem>() });
    autoMocker.Inject(numbers);

    Assert.AreEqual(1, autoMocker.ClassUnderTest.Items.Count());
}
```

Result of the test is:

> Success.

Comment: how is this related to StructureMap?

Comment: Using StructureMap.AutoMocking assembly.

Comment: right, I wasn't aware that existed; I thought it was only related to Rhino Mocks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After taking a look at [the source code for the `AutoMocker<TTargetClass>` class](https://github.com/structuremap/structuremap/blob/master/src/StructureMap/AutoMocking/AutoMocker.cs), I noticed the following:

- AutoMocker uses a StructureMap container under the covers
- usually all dependencies are directly resolved using the container
- dependencies that are of type `IEnumerable<T>` are treated differently (see below)

Here's a piece of code from the `AutoMocker<TTargetClass>` class that shows how constructor dependencies are resolved (I removed some lines for brevity):

```
private object[] getConstructorArgs()
{
    ConstructorInfo ctor = Constructor.GetGreediestConstructor(typeof (TTargetClass));
    var list = new List<object>();
    foreach (ParameterInfo parameterInfo in ctor.GetParameters())
    {
        Type dependencyType = parameterInfo.ParameterType;

        if (dependencyType.IsArray)
        {
            [...]
        }
        else if (dependencyType.Closes(typeof (IEnumerable<>)))
        {
            Type @interface = dependencyType.FindFirstInterfaceThatCloses(typeof (IEnumerable<>));
            Type elementType = @interface.GetGenericArguments().First();

            // Here's the interesting code:
            var builder = typeof (EnumerableBuilder<>).CloseAndBuildAs<IEnumerableBuilder>(_container,
                                                                                           elementType);
            list.Add(builder.ToEnumerable());
        }
        else
        {
            object dependency = _container.GetInstance(dependencyType);
            list.Add(dependency);
        }
    }

    return list.ToArray();
}
```

The code shows that dependencies are usually resolved using `_container.GetInstance`, but there are two exceptions: ararys and `IEnumerable<>`s

For `IEnumerable<T>`, it turns out that `_container.GetAllInstances(typeof(T))` is used. This meas that in your case you should inject several `IItem` instances, not an `IEnumerable<IItem>`. The code responsible for this is the `EnumerableBuilder<T>` class, whih can be found in [the same file](https://github.com/structuremap/structuremap/blob/master/src/StructureMap/AutoMocking/AutoMocker.cs) (at the end).

OK, enough talk. I'm not sure if my explanation is clear enough, so below is code for two tests that pass. Hopefully that will clarify everything:

```
[Test]
public void Test_OneItem()
{
    var autoMocker = new RhinoAutoMocker<TestClass1>();

    autoMocker.Inject(MockRepository.GenerateMock<IItem>());

    Assert.AreEqual(1, autoMocker.ClassUnderTest.Items.Count());
}

[Test]
public void Test_TwoItems()
{
    var autoMocker = new RhinoAutoMocker<TestClass1>();

    autoMocker.Inject(MockRepository.GenerateMock<IItem>());
    autoMocker.Inject(MockRepository.GenerateMock<IItem>());

    Assert.AreEqual(2, autoMocker.ClassUnderTest.Items.Count());
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's really strange behavior.